# Any Java library for 2D vectors (geometry)? Stable/maintained/perspective?

Tags: java, vector, geometry, 2d, vecmath

I'm working on an SVG project, and I need to do some geometrical calculations that work with the 2d vectors. I wonder whether there is some stable, widely used, maintained library for that.
I've found [javax.vecmath](https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.vecmath/vecmath) and its class Vector2d, but the latest release is from 2015, and its homepage is dead.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Apache Commons Math (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/).

> Commons Math is a library of lightweight, self-contained mathematics
> and statistics components addressing the most common problems not
> available in the Java programming language or Commons Lang.

It has Vector2D and many more useful math classes.
(https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/Vector2D.html)